# mod_auth_tkt - java implementation

Tags: java, mod-auth

Has anyone implemented a [mod_auth_tkt](http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/) cookie generation using Java?

I'm stuck on how to generate the iptstamp (can be done in PHP using the pack function) and hextimestamp in Java.

The algorithm for generating the cookie is below:

```
cookie := digest + hextimestamp + user_id + '!' + token_list + '!' + user_data

digest := MD5(digest0 + key)

digest0 := MD5(iptstamp + key + user_id + '\0' + token_list + '\0' + user_data)
```

- `iptstamp` is a 8 bytes long byte array, bytes 0-3 are filled with client's IP address as a binary number in network byte order, bytes 4-7 are filled with timestamp as a binary number in network byte order.
- `hextimestamp` is 8 character long hexadecimal number expressing timestamp used in iptstamp.
- `token_list` is an optional comma-separated list of access tokens for this user.
  This list is checked if TKTAuthToken is set for a particular area.
- `user_data` is optional

Answer (score 1):

Simply convert the IP Address to 4 bytes and append the timestamp.

```
iptstamp = ip_chars + ts_chars
```

http://code.cmlenz.net/diva/changeset/173/branches
http://www.mail-archive.com/modauthtkt-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00003.html

Using the following to get network byte order.

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
```

See

[Network Order short (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991998/network-order-short-java)